# npm install q --save only saves in devDependencies

Tags: npm

I am getting the strangest behavior where `npm install q --save` is only installing q in devDependencies, never in dependencies.  This is true for any module, not just q.  No matter which install flags I use, modules are only ever saved in devDependencies.

I switched between multiple versions of npm including the latest stable version and the behavior is the same every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I tracked this down to my `~/.npmrc` file which contained the following:

```
save = true
save-dev =
```

I changed it to this:

```
save = false
save-dev = false
```

And now `npm install q --save` correctly saves into dependencies!

Comment: I can confirm this and would consider this is a bug.